# How can I open a modal form and call a module from a button click procedure on another form in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog, showdialog

Here is my current code for the button click procedure.  My module is called Summary.vb, and the modal form I am trying to open is frmSummary.  The Form opens but nothing in my module is executed.

```
Private Sub btnSummary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSummary.Click
    Dim frmSum As New frmSummary
    Dim intScoreType As Integer = 1
    frmSum.ShowDialog()
    DisplaySummary(1, intSAT, Max_Size)
End Sub
```

And here is the first part of my module:

```
Sub DisplaySummary(ByVal intScoreType As Integer, ByVal intScores() As Integer, ByVal Max_Size As Integer)
```

Comment: Can you share what errors you are getting or any more info?

Comment: You do realise that DisplaySummary won't be called until frmSum closes?